# Determining the sampling rate / frequency from a graph

Tags: signal, signal-processing, bandwidth, sampling

I don't understand how the two graphs in the image below are connected. The context is signal processing and sampling rate (+ its relation to bandwidth). I don't know the exact terms to look up. I am a computer science student and don't know much about electrical engineering / signal processing, I would appreciate it if you answer accordingly (with simpler terms in a universally understandable language).

[image]

Comment: Including the context for the pictures would help, but the one on the right is probably the Fourier transform of the one on the left. Do you know what a Fourier transform is?

Comment: It does not matter if it's a Fourier or some other transform, the point is on the left there is the sampled signal in time domain and on the right the same sampled signal in frequency domain. Explaining all what you ask is not a short thing to do, as it basically covers a multi-page chapter about sampling in a DSP book. Try reading the Wikipedia article on sampling theorem.After that you will be able to determine from the picture the signal bandwidth and sampling rate easily. Also in a typical university, DSP is more closer to CS studies than EE.

Answer (score 1):

An analog signal, \$x(t)\$, is continuous in both time and amplitude. An analog signal has (generally) a non-periodic frequency spectrum \$X(\omega)\$. So

$$x(t) \Leftrightarrow X(\omega) $$

A time-discrete signal, \$y(n\Delta t)\$, is discrete in time, but can still be continuous in amplitude. A time-discrete signal can be represented as an analog signal mulitipled by a [Dirac-delta comb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_comb), \$y(n\Delta t) = x(t) \cdot \delta_s\$, where \$ \delta_s = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \delta(t-n\Delta t)\$, and \$ \Delta t = \frac{1}{f_s}\$.

The frequency spectrum of a time-discrete signal will be periodic, since multiplication in time corresponds to convolving in frequency, so

$$x(t) \cdot \delta_s \Leftrightarrow X(\omega) \ast \Delta_s $$

The dashed line in the time-domain in your graph is an analog signal. The dots on the dashed line signify discrete samples (i.e. the set of all the dots constitute a discrete signal). The blue graph on the right shows a frequency spectrum that is periodic. This spectrum presumably stems from the discrete-time signal's Fourier-Transform.